# preallocate python variable in separate function

Tags: python

I have a script that I would like to remove the pre-allocation of variables and move it into another script (function). For example, I would like to take the following portion of code from 'script1.py':

```
var1 = {}
var2 = {}
var3 = {}
```

And put this into 'function1.py':

```
def preallocate_vars():
    var1 = {}
    var2 = {}
    var3 = {}
```

I can then call the function 'preallocate_vars' via 'function1.py' from 'script1.py' and then continue on my business. Something like:

script1.py

```
from function1 import preallocate_vars

..
(do some work)
..
preallocate_vars()
..
(do some more work)
..
var1[0] = data1
var2[0] = data2
var3[0] = data3
...
```

However, when I try something like this, I get an error that 'var1 is not defined' in my script1.py. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Why would you need to "preallocate" variables? Either way, `function1` is a separate module from `script1` - they won't share variables.

Comment: You'll need to use `function1.varX` to access those variables.

Comment: It would be better to have the function return the variables instead of assigning them. Then you can use `var1, var2, var3 = preallocate_vars()`